# sql query for change column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change my column name but there is space between name how can I change

```
--ALTER TABLE awbuildversion RENAME COLUMN `Database Version` to DatabaseVersion

--ALTER TABLE awbuildversion RENAME COLUMN `Database Version` to `DatabaseVersion`
```

i tried above but not working

Comment: Double quotes, i.e. `"Database Version"`.

Comment: write column name with space like this: `[Database Version]`

Comment: @Nino, that's only valid for MS SQL Server, double quotes is specified by the ANSI SQL standard, and afaik works with SQL Server as well.

Comment: you are right, thank you.

Comment: Which dbms are you using here?

Comment: @halfer, how come you edited to MySQL style delimited identifers?

Comment: @jarlh: I didn't - they were in there already, but hidden because they were not formatted correctly using Markdown.

Comment: @halfer, I understand. So OP is obviously using MySQL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for MS SQL Server:

```
 EXEC sp_RENAME '[awbuildversion].[Database Version]' , 'DatabaseVersion', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

To make things a bit clearer. Delimited identifiers are needed for identifiers that contain odd characters and space etc.

ANSI SQL has double quotes, e.g. `"Database Version"`.

SQL Server also has square brackets, e.g. `[Database Version]`.

MySQL only has back-ticks, ... (*How to write those????*)